# CSS, Idiom for Preferred min width

Tags: html, css

I have learned from similar questions that `min-width` always beats `max-width`, which is unfortunate, because I think modern websites mostly require it the other way around.

I often have to resort to media queries to solve the below problem, but hoping there is an elegant/better solution:

Say I have a `div`:

```
<div>Words on a page. Words on a page. Words on a page. Words on a page.</div>
```

I often wish to have this `div` width to be at least 500px, as long as it's not bigger than 90% of the screen width. This can be accomplished with:

```
div {
    min-width: 500px;
    max-width: 90vw;
}
```

Now the problem with the above is it overflows on mobile.
I encounter this all time when I have a list of objects, and say the items are deletable, then if one deletes the widest element, the whole design jumps as it resizes. To minimize this effect, I wish to have a default width and allow it to expand in rare cases as needed.

Comment: Sounds like you need a "responsive design."  There are comprehensive, mature techniques for doing that.

Comment: _"Now the problem with the above is it never expands beyond 500px."_ - why should it, with an explicitly specified width of 500px? It sounds like you actually want `min-width: 500px` there - and I can't see what the problem with that is supposed to be? That it doesn't go _below_ 500px, if the screen width doesn't allow for that? Well that's a problem you would have with both `width` and `min-width` the same way, so for smaller screen resolutions this would require a media query to set a different (min-)width either way.

Comment: @CBroe fair point I updated it.

Comment: I've read this slightly differently. To me, "at least 500px but not bigger than 90% of the screen width" just means `width: 90vw`. Because "at least 500px" could mean any width at all once you add in your condition. It almost sounds like what you really want is `width: 90vw; max-width: *some upper bound*;`.

Comment: I think you want a fixed min-width, but dependent on a _condition_ (and that condition being, a minimum screen width) - and the basic tool to express such conditions, simply _are_ media queries. But perhaps you can cobble something together out of min()/max(), that fulfills the same purpose ...? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min()

Comment: @lawrence-witt i think it's 90vw but if less than 500px then it should 100% (100vw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below:

```css
div {
  min-width: min(500px, 100%); /* will take less than 500px if there is an overflow */
  max-width: 90vw;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>Words on a page. Words on a page. Words on a page. Words on a page.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to set the min-width to no more than 90% of the width of the screen but if the screen is wide enough then 500px.

If so maybe try:

```css
div {
  min-width: min(500px, 90vw);
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text </div>
```